# Copy paste based on column header

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

The following piece of code works great for me except that it stops when it gets an empty row in the column.

I would like to modify it by determining to copy-paste until the last row in column `A`. I have made a `LASTROW` variable, but I can not figure out where to use it exactly.

```
LASTROW = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy    Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
Dim headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)),  Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tryed this way?

```
For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0).Address, Worksheets("ws1").Cells(Rows.Count, header.Column).End(xlUp).Address).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: HI, thank you for your suggestion but his solutions goes to "run time error1004,  Method 'Range' of 'object '_Global' failed".

Comment: @toth_jani I added the sheet name. Check if it works now

Comment: I tried but still the same issue. Can I send somehow the file to check? Thx

Comment: @toth_jani I'm not sure of what you need but now the code seems to work